# How to hide an app in the Application Manager

Tags: android

I want to make my Android application invisible and work through a background task.
This part should work like these two apps, if anyone knows them:

https://www.keeperschildsafety.net/

https://www2.mspy.com/

I already found examples for making the app icon invisible, but I want to go one step further.
This is the site I found that on:

https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/hideunhide-app-icon-programmatically-android/

I also found some explanations that I should delete the `<intent-filter>`:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

But then I am not able to start my application.
On all other sites I read that this is not possible, but the two examples shown at the top prove that it is actually possible somehow.

I want to start my application once, then hide it and unhide it later.
I already know how to trigger the unhide. The only part that I need is the hiding and unhiding itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following line from your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

This will remove the application from the default launcher. However, you also need to add the following line such that your BroadcastReceiver is not completely ignored:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

You should NOT remove the line below - it is used to specify which Activity should launch first when your app is opened:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

also try this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" ...
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml's activity declaration.

Comment: Ok, i got this so far. The only problem is, that it is still visible in the ApplicationManager and I want to hide it there too.
Do you have any suggestions for it?

Comment: no you cannot hide app but you can keep your app name like system app, wifi, bluetooth, etc.